# How to set ClientIDRowSuffix on nested ListView when using XmlDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, datasource, asp.net-4.0

I've got an `XmlDataSouce` with Movies and Actors. I would like to list the each movie with the specified actors. I'm using `ListView` controls with `ClientIDMode="Predictable"` and a `ClientIDRowSuffix` to make sure I'll end up with IDs I can use in my javascript.

I have the following `XmlDataSource`:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server">
    <Data>
        <Movies>
            <Movie Name="What Dreams May Come" Ranking="7" MovieId="6546" >
                <Actor FullName="Robin Williams" ActorId="1573" />
                <Actor FullName="Cuba Gooding" ActorId="1957" />
            </Movie>
            <Movie Name="A Beautiful Mind" Ranking="10" MovieId="5151" >
                <Actor FullName="Russell Crowe" ActorId="1231" />
                <Actor FullName="Ed Harris " ActorId="1923" />
            </Movie>
        </Movies>
    </Data>
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Now I would like to view it:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable"
                     ClientIDRowSuffix="MovieId" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="item" runat="server" clientidmode="Predictable">
            Name: <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /><br /> 
            Actors:
            <asp:ListView ID="Actors" runat="server" 
                          ClientIDMode="Predictable" ClientIDRowSuffix="ActorId" 
                          DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("Actor") %>' />
                <ItemTemplate> 
                        <asp:Label ID="lblActorName" runat="server" 
                                   Text='<%# XPath("@FullName") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemSeparatorTemplate>,</ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:ListView> 
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

It looks great, but it throws the following exception:

> DataBinding: 'System.Xml.XmlElement' does not contain a property with
>   the name 'ActorId'.

**How can I set the right `ClientIDRowSuffix`?**

Comments are highly appreciated.

<sub>Ps. I've used `<%# Eval() %>` but that one binds to the movie record.</sub>

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes i tried that. It throws the same exception, 'does not contain a property with the name '@ActorId'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer, but you're not going to like it, as it involves a piece of custom code. It seems the `ClientIdRowSuffix` needs a property, so I've created my own method. This method needs the node set and the name of the id attribute.

```
<script runat="server">

    public IEnumerable EvalIDNode(IEnumerable element, string idAttribute)
    {
        foreach (System.Xml.XmlElement node in element)
        {
            yield return new CustomNode(node, idAttribute);
        }
    }

    public class CustomNode : System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable
    {
        private System.Xml.XmlElement _node;

        public string IDField { get; private set; }

        public CustomNode(System.Xml.XmlElement node, string idAttribute)
        {
            _node = node;
            IDField = node.Attributes[idAttribute].Value;
        }

        public System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator CreateNavigator()
        {
            return _node.CreateNavigator();
        }
    }

</script>
```

We'll use the method to get the data source on the `ListField`:

```
<asp:ListView
          ID="Actors" 
          runat="server"  
          ClientIDMode="Predictable" 
          ClientIDRowSuffix="IDField"
          DataSource='<%# EvalIDNode(XPathSelect("Actor"), "ActorId") %>'>
```

Notice the `ClientIdRowSuffix` it is set to **IDField**. It ain't pretty, but it gets the job done. I'm not sure if the binding goes well if you would use textboxes and two way binding.